# R.NET crashes when I run the whetting appetite app

Tags: c#, .net, r, r.net

The following didn't work for me. Simply crashes with no exception caught.

```
REngine engine = null;
try
{
    REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables(@"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3\bin\x64", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

    engine = REngine.GetInstance();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
   Console.ReadKey();
   return;
}
```

I installed R for Windows version 3.2.3 without the registry option.

I am using R.NET.Community version 1.6.5 targeting .NET framework 4.0.

I tried the path @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3\bin\i386" as well and I get

> %1 is not a valid Win32 application
>   Error: This 64-bit process failed to load the library R.dll. Native error message is 'The system cannot find the file specified'

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Call M$ ... you did pay your subscription fee didn't you?

Comment: haha that's a good one. I got it working anyway. See my answer

Answer (score 4):

Ok I got it working.

You need to target the 64-bit version of R. I read somewhere the recent R developments are geared towards 64-bit Windows.

You need the registry entries. You can do so by executing RSetReg.exe in the R bin directory.

After that, simply do this and it will work:

```
REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();
engine = REngine.GetInstance();
```

I have tested this on R 3.2.3 and RRO 3.2.2 and they both work with Rdotnet 1.6.5.

Comment: The call to `REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();` is not required. That call is made implicitly by the call to `REngine.GetInstance();`.